# "did you sign up successfully?" - what's wrong with this sentence?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-participles

If someone says, they are going to try signing up on a certain website, how should I check if they managed to do that?

> Did you sign up successfully?

looks very odd, although I can't think of another way to say it.

Comment: Why do you think it looks 'odd'?

Comment: Google brings up only few results for this phrase.

Answer (score 3):

"Did you sign up successfully" is correct English and means what you think it means.

You may not find many hits on google as this would more likely be spoken (or emailed) than written on a website. There are also lots of ways to ask something similar:

> Did you get signed up?
>   I heard you were trying to set up a gmail account. How did that go?
>   Were there any problems signing up?

There is rarely only one "correct" way to say something.